# Another reference for higher order Fourier analysis

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to read Tao's *Higher order Fourier analysis* but I would be very happy to find another book on the subject. I would like to learn something about the Gowers norm and about Roth's theorem (density increment and energy increment arguments). Sorry if this question is a bit too open ended . Lecture notes, even separately on each topic I just mentioned are absolutely fine.

Part of the reason is that I am not sure what the natural context for Fourier measurability and complexity is, whatever natural means and I was hoping I could understand these if I had another reference. Thanks!

Comment: You may also find helpful this relatively recent survey of Gowers: https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04127 . A published version appeared in the Bulletin of the AMS.

Comment: @BradRodgers Thanks, I'll take a detailed look at this. It seems like the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try "Nilpotent structures in Ergodic theory" by Host and Kra, which covers this topic in greater depth.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I shall take a look at this book.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of references I have found immensely useful, incidentally co-written by the same author.

1. [The primes contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v167-n2-p03.pdf), Annals of Mathematics,167(2008), 481–547.
2. [Green B., Tao T. (2010) An Arithmetic Regularity Lemma, An Associated Counting Lemma, and Applications.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-14444-8_7) In: Bárány I., Solymosi J., Sági G. (eds) An Irregular Mind. Bolyai Society Mathematical Studies, vol 21. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.

Note that the notion of Fourier-measurability in the book listed above coincides with that of s-measurability in the second paper (Def 2.2).